Rates Curve 'Realising' vs 'Rolling'
Just saw an exchange on X and would appreciate if anyone could try their hand at going into a bit more detail (and even maybe using an example) to breakdown the conceptual difference of rates curves 'rolling' vs 'realising' when it comes to interest rates curves
Also - if someone could explain what is meant by the "something clever to interpolate if you want to calc roll" that would be an amazing bonus.
Question - I am unclear on what is meant by the below:
"Bond rolling down = spot curve is unchanged. So your 5y bond which you’ve held for a year has the same yield as a 4y bond a year ago (when you bot the 5y). Curve realizing = the 5y bond you’ve held for a year now yields what the 1y forward 4y yield was a year ago.
An explanation was given, but i dont quite follow:
I think the natural way to think about it is that, if the Fed is predicted to cut in three weeks, then what is the overnight rate in four weeks. Realised = the lower rate. Rolled= the Fed didn’t cut but is also still predicted to cut in three weeks.
*Generally curves realise in the front end but roll in the long end. That is features like 10y30y are a generic and persistent term premium but the first 18 months are genuine time dependent predictions and you have to do something clever to interpolate if you want to calc roll.
*
Edit: I realise if you're a seasoned practitioner you might be thinking that the above is already an explanation. What I mean is can you explain it to someone like they are a child.

"Roll" is the (less realistic) scenario  that at time $T_1$, the interest rate curve will be exactly what it was at time $T_0$. E.g., whatever the 1 year par rate you see at  $T_0$, it will be exactly the same at $T_1$. "Forwards realized" is the (somewhat more realistic) scenario, in which the forwards that are implied by the spot curve at $T_0$, later get realized  at  $T_1$, i.e. become spot rates, absent new information.. E.g. suppose that at  $T_0$ you observe the 6M and 18M rates, which imply  the "1Y in 6 months" forward rate. And in 6 months, you can observe the 1Y rate and compare.

It comes down to the general question whether a forward curve is an unbiased forecast of the future (in which case it will "realize", on average), or whether it is a result of term premia (temporary or due to structural factors) in which case it will maintain its shape to some extent i.e. "rolling"). Is the 30 year rate higher than the Tbill rate because the market expects the Tbill rate to go up in the years ahead or because it is almost always more expensive to borrow long term? Obviously in reality it could be some of both.

Realising at the short end, implies that the market is fairly good at predicting future rates, that is the forwards are good estimators of future spot rates. Therefore, any money you earn from carry is offset /compensated by future rate moves. At the long end, the market is not great at predicting where the long term rates will go to, therefore, an unchanged yield curve is a lot more reasonable assumption as opposed to forward rates being realised.

When you look at how various curves have changed over a small time horizon, eg 1 day, it is sometimes insightful to see how much of the changes are attributable to the forwards being realized versus new information, and this calculation is easy to set up.
